# php reverse date function

Tags: php

I wondered if anybody knew of a way to reverse the date function in php.
For example.. if I want to printed the day / month / year / time I would do:

```
date("d jS M, Y", strtotime("2012-01-01 12:12:12"));
```

If I had Sat 1st January, 2012 12.12pm - is there a way to reverse this to output "2012-01-01 12:12:12".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is a little vague, but I think all you should need to do is change the format: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at PHP's [`DateTime` class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It's a lot more flexible than the old-style `date()` function and it's friends.

In your case, it sounds like you need [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). This function is great if you have an input date string in a known format. With the old style `strtotime()` function, you couldn't specify the format, so it had to work it out for itself (and in some cases it guessed wrongly).

This example is from the manual page:

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, '2009-02-15 15:16:17');
echo "Format: $format; " . $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
```

The format string accepted by `createFromFormat` is the same type as you know and love from the old `date()` function, so work out what your format would be if you wanted to output it, and you'll have the solution.

Therefore, given the formats you specified in the question, you could write this:

```
$inputDateString = "Sat 1st January, 2012 12.12pm";
$dateObject = DateTime::createFromFormat("D jS M, Y h.ia",$inputDateString);
print $dateObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

This will output `2012-01-01 12:12:00`

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 7):

Try This

The real answer to this question the way I mean it is http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php

```
<?php
$date = date_create_from_format('j-M-Y', '15-Oct-2012');
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`strptime()` does something like that, but not exactly (you should write your own function for that based on `strptime`)

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strptime.php

**Edit**:

Or, in PHP 5.3+: `date_parse_from_format`

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php

Answer (score 0):

in an easy way, we can do like this

```
$date = '26-07-2016';
echo date("Y/m/d",strtotime($date));

output: 2016/07/26
```

Change the format as per your requirement

Answer (score -1):

```
{function rev_date($date){
  $array=explode("-",$date);
            $rev=array_reverse($array);
            $date=implode("-",$rev);
            return $date;
}}
```